# Understand architecture of MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, n-tier-architecture

There are many articles available to explain architecture design of MVC application , some contains business layers , domain layers and etc.

I would like to know each & every terms and what should be inside that layer?

> Presentation.Web : MVC application goes here
>  Business.Domain :
>   ??
>  Infrastructure.Data : ??

What are others layers should be there to and what is use of that to create ideal architecture of MVC application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This nice article by Russell East could help you out - http://russelleast.wordpress.com/2009/04/04/aspnet-mvc-defining-an-application-architecture/

Answer (score 2):

I will try and explain it in a technology neutral format:

mvc is short for model , view, controller.

===========================================

Model isn't the girl/boy walking down the stairway showing off trendy clothes.
But its an object that contains valuable properties (data)

For instance:
In RPG (role playing game) every character has stats such as
health , magic, attack, defense, evasion, accuracy, etc.

Those stats are called properties in classes.
Character acts as a class that contains all those properties.

===========================================

Now, talking about the View,
View is something that displays about a particular model.

For example:
We have a health bar that display total health and current health.

Some might be interested to see a heart shape to represent health
instead of a red bar.

The developer starts creating another different view but still uses the same model . It's talking about reusability!

You are reusing the same model to display its properties in many ways!

============================================

For the controller, its the place where your business logic is defined.
Business logic (or also known as the 'fun' part of coding)
is a place where you define some code to manipulate the properties in 
model and send them to the view.

For example:
So let's assumed that the hero has full health,
An enemy attack him...

The controller (who has access to the model) manipulates your 
Character health by deducting current health by total damage received
from enemy attack.

When your character drinks a health potion, 
the controller increments your character current health.

==========================================

For the communication part,
the controller who manipulates the model,
can inform the view about the changes made,
so that the view will display the most recent changes to your character.

Or

the model dispatches event whenever a property has been changed,
and the view who is currently subscribing to a model ,
will then take necessary actions to update the view by using the current
manipulated property.

You can also have a look at this [link](http://jordanhall.co.uk/programming/simple-explanation-of-model-view-controller-mvc-2206990/)

Answer (score 0):

The following might explain:

MVC Architecture

The main aim of the MVC architecture  is to separate the business logic and application data from the presentation data to the user.

Here are the reasons why we should use the MVC design pattern.

They are resuable : When the problems recurs, there is no need to invent a new solution, we just have to follow the pattern and adapt it as necessary.
They are expressive: By using the MVC design pattern our application becomes more expressive.

1).  Model: The model object knows about all the data that need to be displayed. It is model who is aware about all the operations that can be applied to transform that object. It only represents the data of an application. The model represents enterprise data and the business rules that govern access to and updates of this data. Model is not aware about the presentation data and how that data will be displayed to the browser.

2). View : The view represents the presentation of the application. The view object refers to the model. It uses the query methods of the model to obtain the contents and renders it. The view is not dependent on the application logic. It remains same if there is any modification in the business logic. In other words, we can say that it is the responsibility of the of the view's to maintain the consistency in its presentation when the model changes.

3). Controller:  Whenever the user sends a request for something then it always go through the controller. The controller is responsible for intercepting the requests from view and passes it to the model for the appropriate action. After the action has been taken on the data, the controller is responsible for directing the appropriate view to the user. In  GUIs, the views and the controllers often work very closely together.

Source: http://www.roseindia.net/struts/mvc-architecture.shtml